# Direct String quicker than a String Variable?

Tags: java, string, variables

```
    final String string1 = "somestring1";
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        final String string2 = "somestring2";
        if (string2.equals(string1)) { // Using variable
            // do stuff
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        final String string2 = "somestring2";
        if (string2.equals("somestring1")) { // Not using variable
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Which of them would actually be quicker?

1) The first one would save it as a variable and use the variable until the cycle is completed.

2) The second one is going to generate a new String everytime, isn't it?

This is only an example, in my case milliseconds would matter alot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: #2 will not create a new string every time but it will have to check the pool and retrieve the intern each time. See String interning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: @Radiodef: What makes you think that the interned string will have to be looked up each time?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I've read that a few places. Why wouldn't it have to be retrieved? And the JLS states that String literals are interned by way of the method `String#intern` whose doc specifies that the pool is queried.

Comment: It wouldn't have to be retrieved because when the string is interned once when the class is loaded, after which it just becomes a fixed pointer to the string in the intern pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to try and see what happens:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int numOfTrials = 100000;

    long first = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < numOfTrials; index++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        final String string1 = "somestring1";
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            final String string2 = "somestring2";
            if (string2.equals(string1)) { // Using variable
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        first+= (System.nanoTime()-start);
    }

    long second = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < numOfTrials; index++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            final String string2 = "somestring2";
            if (string2.equals("somestring1")) { // Not using variable
                // do stuff
            }
        }
        second+= (System.nanoTime()-start);
    }


    System.out.println("First : "+(first/numOfTrials)+"ns");
    System.out.println("Second : "+second/numOfTrials+"ns");
}
```

numOfTrials = 10000

Outputs

```
First : 139ns
Second : 59ns
```

There is a caching mechanism inside the JVM and JVM will not create new string objects if there is already one matching and use the existing one instead. There are ways to force jvm to create new strings like the keyword "new". You might need to find an article and read it if you want to go deeper.

---

numOfTrials = 1 million

output:

```
First : 42ns
Second : 34ns
```

---

numOfTrials = 100 million

output:

```
First : 31ns
Second : 31ns
```

Answer (score 0):

This first version (listed below) will execute faster, since it only creates the String once.

```
final String string1 = "somestring1";
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    final String string2 = "somestring2";
    if (string2.equals(string1)) { // Using variable
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These will both be 100% equivalent.  There is no difference, not even milliseconds.